# Python: Move specific lists within list, based on an element, at the end

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list which contains other lists. Each element of this list contains 5 elements, like so:

```
requests = [['abc', 'def', 'abc.def@email.com', 'GROUP1', '000'],
           ['ghi', 'jkl', 'ghi,jkl@email.com', 'GROUP4', '111'],
           ['mno', 'pqr', 'mno.pqr@email.com', 'GROUP4', '222'],
           ['stu', 'vxy', 'stu.vxy@email.com', 'GROUP2', '333'],
           ['123', '456', '123.456@email.com', 'GROUP4', '444'],
           ['A12', 'B34', 'A12.B34f@email.com', 'GROUP3', '555']]
```

I would like to sort this list, in such a way that each list that contains an element equal to GROUP4, will be placed at the end of the list. So, the output would look like this:

```
requests = [['abc', 'def', 'abc.def@email.com', 'GROUP1', '000'],
           ['stu', 'vxy', 'stu.vxy@email.com', 'GROUP2', '333'],
           ['A12', 'B34', 'A12.B34f@email.com', 'GROUP3', '555'],
           ['ghi', 'jkl', 'ghi,jkl@email.com', 'GROUP4', '111'],
           ['mno', 'pqr', 'mno.pqr@email.com', 'GROUP4', '222'],
           ['123', '456', '123.456@email.com', 'GROUP4', '444'],]
```

I managed to sort them based on that specific element using:

```
requests.sort(key=lambda x: x[3])
```

But this just sorts them alphabetically, based on the 4th element. This won't work if a GROUP5 or GROUP6 is present, as those 2 will be the last elements.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try this simple change - 
`requests.sort(key=lambda x: x[3] == "GROUP4")`  Use the trick of `True` when 3rd item is `GROUP4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the `lambda` to check if the 4th item is `'GROUP4'`

```
requests.sort(key=lambda x: x[3] == 'GROUP4')
```

If you want to sort the rest of the list as well use `tuple` in the `lambda` with two items, it will sort by `'GROUP4'` first and then by lexicography order

```
requests.sort(key=lambda x: (x[3] == 'GROUP4', x[3]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Move lists with GROUP4 at index [3] to the end by sorting by boolean.

```
requests.sort(key=lambda el: el[3] == "GROUP4")
```

Comment: I think you could elaborate your answer by specifying that `.sort` is guaranteed to be a stable sort, which in this case means that your code snippet will only move `"GROUP4"` elements to the end of the list, with no other modification of the order of elements.